# Docker Swarm DNS resolving failing randomly

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a three node swarm, with a master node, and some stacks running (all sharing a network). From time to time, applications fail without being able to resolve internal DNS names. They just get back to work when updating the service that failed to resolve that name.

The services are using a common network:

```
networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

Using inspect, the created network shows:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "traefik-public",
        "Id": "hwtew3nwv25f0hnpihozekude",
        "Created": "2021-03-29T21:35:15.564221398+02:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.7.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.7.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0d110ab118c41eef958553d8d9c8970034ee346b481c1ccd520e3a1ed49297fa": {
                "Name": "minion_minion_mysql.1.b6mq8432g5b0srabg73lk833q",
                "EndpointID": "0f363678f9c419475918d83c6b69b065a28b17040b34c696e7b630bebbf30402",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:79",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.121/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3b1321643a2c7660a678591f3ed74b7facd338a9ab5c29ede63f188e35e016ba": {
                "Name": "minion_minion_ui.1.9e9cqqbvzuv2rf4e13f7cwbty",
                "EndpointID": "ad58ff109bf74387cef8f6a537a7e8be20dc7c239ea17a888e486c45fd3641cb",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:77",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.119/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "63590dafe7978133f114a53ed6816d73e9bd18f81778d6f9a169f13ae2bb2462": {
                "Name": "swarmpit_app.1.xalzfuq9mbg7t6k4w0x3bspu7",
                "EndpointID": "b4b0716458b0b77882b4cd5220fef8ab667683c4ffc1f1d9992a0c1845f8041f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:f3",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.243/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "91e9ff38ed632d8290a9288026af719486b86f5bf2cd612e39fcbfb5aea13cc3": {
                "Name": "minio_minio1.1.ozqa8faxgp07c6ubon6xq3bwj",
                "EndpointID": "9edacf297796afda9bce22d47a635c0f87d974faeda2ae21112bde3927853949",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:2b",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.43/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d0944d673c2a0eda051a16822a0f301973f98efb8ac0d9f140993306e859a562": {
                "Name": "mediadb_mediadb_anc.1.xbq9wnk84cii7bvzjt2968k7a",
                "EndpointID": "9cfc100ccec631b134accc0f3dabf1d28009819318710a028ab9b471b440f3dc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:46",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.70/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e6b84654afede231cd9e52573082c312b3c89d31c3ce34c605be944c3147e1cd": {
                "Name": "traefik_traefik.1.rf0hmr3dyh2l3y6iyt3ysry5t",
                "EndpointID": "2a3066d76c42fdee6871b9fce19917a6ad9e363c11e94bf23f5f1f6fb033e445",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:f5",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.245/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f8af470ce571cf7a6b3cf90408eb1ba40721fa930b820dd74d4d1840d49b84d6": {
                "Name": "mediadb_mediadb_amo.1.egtd13w29iqzjm1tl4mebpynd",
                "EndpointID": "9fa4bf4543d1866ff82f95ee3912744fba156a3127dbe0c54b94919eddbadcd1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:f7",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.247/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-traefik-public": {
                "Name": "traefik-public-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "04846d313ae4772083066dd4b0fad7b71538ea496b02624da8317608374c6481",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:07:df",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.7.223/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4101"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "70731e7a2f28",
                "IP": "192.168.133.101"
            },
            {
                "Name": "d4ef9d5dd73f",
                "IP": "192.168.133.102"
            },
            {
                "Name": "62b8966e8aca",
                "IP": "192.168.133.103"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am running docker version 20.10.5, running on a Fedora box.

Any idea on how to fix these issues, or how to debug them, is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your services are likely caching the DNS.  Best is to reduce or remove the DNS caching for your service.

Comment: The services are running for a long time, and their IP should not change, so not really understanding how that might be the problem. Can you give some pointers? Thanks